# How to Make ExpressJs Dynamic Routes Appear In Google Results? (mysite.com/user/:UserID)

Tags: node.js, backbone.js, express, seo, phantomjs

Im building a single page app with NodeJS/ExpressJS & Backbone/Marionette.

My App consists of routes like mysite.com/user/:UserID in which :UserID matches up with any of the thousands of users in my database. So if someone types mysite.com/user/1234, the profile of user '1234' appears.

But now i'm confused in how to get each dynamically loaded profile to appear in a static google search?

For example how sites like Facebook or Twitter have a User Profile appear and indexed when I search it on Google, even though it has the appearance of a single page app.

I've been researching the following solutions, but not sure which will lead me to what im trying to accomplish:

1) PhantomJS snapshots

2) Make Isomorphic App(using Facebook's react.js or Airbnb Rendr)

3) Change URL's to hashbang #! format (appears to be outdated in favor of backbone pushstate)

4) Use Prerender: https://github.com/prerender/prerender-node

Also read up on SEO and dynamically loaded content appearing on Search Results, but im not sure if its the same thing.

I've Done the following:

1) Using Backbone PushState in that url address bar changes to the new profile clicked without reloading the page.

2) Set up express routes so when user types in address bar , then 'Enter', mysite.com/user/1234, it loads profile '1234'